Is there a more stable way than -webkit-tap-highlight-color?
Hide the blue highlight that appears on elements when tapped on touch devices or mobile devices, it is true that -webkit-tap-highlight-color works, but unfortunately according to MDN:

Non-standard: This feature is non-standard and is not on a standards
track. Do not use it on production sites facing the Web: it will not
work for every user. There may also be large incompatibilities between
implementations and the behavior may change in the future.

Are there other methods that are more stable or work better?
example :

